# iVar Shown as Private Global In LLVMIR

Tags: objective-c, xcode, clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I have declared a iVar in a class:

```
@implementation LLVMIRTest{
    NSString* ivarTest;
}
```

When I check for LLVM IR it shows me:

```
@OBJC_METH_VAR_NAME_ = private global [9 x i8] c"ivarTest\00", section "__TEXT,__objc_methname,cstring_literals", align 1
@OBJC_METH_VAR_TYPE_ = private global [12 x i8] c"@\22NSString\22\00", section "__TEXT,__objc_methtype,cstring_literals", align 1
```

I have to ask why it is private global mention in LLVM IR. Why not only private?

This is full Module LLVM IR:

```
; ModuleID = 'LLVMIRTest.m'
source_filename = "LLVMIRTest.m"
target datalayout = "e-m:o-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-apple-macosx10.12.0"

%struct._objc_cache = type opaque
%struct._class_t = type { %struct._class_t*, %struct._class_t*, %struct._objc_cache*, i8* (i8*, i8*)**, %struct._class_ro_t* }
%struct._class_ro_t = type { i32, i32, i32, i8*, i8*, %struct.__method_list_t*, %struct._objc_protocol_list*, %struct._ivar_list_t*, i8*, %struct._prop_list_t* }
%struct.__method_list_t = type { i32, i32, [0 x %struct._objc_method] }
%struct._objc_method = type { i8*, i8*, i8* }
%struct._objc_protocol_list = type { i64, [0 x %struct._protocol_t*] }
%struct._protocol_t = type { i8*, i8*, %struct._objc_protocol_list*, %struct.__method_list_t*, %struct.__method_list_t*, %struct.__method_list_t*, %struct.__method_list_t*, %struct._prop_list_t*, i32, i32, i8**, i8*, %struct._prop_list_t* }
%struct._ivar_list_t = type { i32, i32, [0 x %struct._ivar_t] }
%struct._ivar_t = type { i64*, i8*, i8*, i32, i32 }
%struct._prop_list_t = type { i32, i32, [0 x %struct._prop_t] }
%struct._prop_t = type { i8*, i8* }

@_objc_empty_cache = external global %struct._objc_cache
@"OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSObject" = external global %struct._class_t
@OBJC_CLASS_NAME_ = private global [11 x i8] c"LLVMIRTest\00", section "__TEXT,__objc_classname,cstring_literals", align 1
@"\01l_OBJC_METACLASS_RO_$_LLVMIRTest" = private global %struct._class_ro_t { i32 1, i32 40, i32 40, i8* null, i8* getelementptr inbounds ([11 x i8], [11 x i8]* @OBJC_CLASS_NAME_, i32 0, i32 0), %struct.__method_list_t* null, %struct._objc_protocol_list* null, %struct._ivar_list_t* null, i8* null, %struct._prop_list_t* null }, section "__DATA, __objc_const", align 8
@"OBJC_METACLASS_$_LLVMIRTest" = global %struct._class_t { %struct._class_t* @"OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSObject", %struct._class_t* @"OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSObject", %struct._objc_cache* @_objc_empty_cache, i8* (i8*, i8*)** null, %struct._class_ro_t* @"\01l_OBJC_METACLASS_RO_$_LLVMIRTest" }, section "__DATA, __objc_data", align 8
@"OBJC_CLASS_$_NSObject" = external global %struct._class_t
@"OBJC_IVAR_$_LLVMIRTest.ivarTest" = hidden global i64 8, section "__DATA, __objc_ivar", align 8
@OBJC_METH_VAR_NAME_ = private global [9 x i8] c"ivarTest\00", section "__TEXT,__objc_methname,cstring_literals", align 1
@OBJC_METH_VAR_TYPE_ = private global [12 x i8] c"@\22NSString\22\00", section "__TEXT,__objc_methtype,cstring_literals", align 1
@"\01l_OBJC_$_INSTANCE_VARIABLES_LLVMIRTest" = private global { i32, i32, [1 x %struct._ivar_t] } { i32 32, i32 1, [1 x %struct._ivar_t] [%struct._ivar_t { i64* @"OBJC_IVAR_$_LLVMIRTest.ivarTest", i8* getelementptr inbounds ([9 x i8], [9 x i8]* @OBJC_METH_VAR_NAME_, i32 0, i32 0), i8* getelementptr inbounds ([12 x i8], [12 x i8]* @OBJC_METH_VAR_TYPE_, i32 0, i32 0), i32 3, i32 8 }] }, section "__DATA, __objc_const", align 8
@"\01l_OBJC_CLASS_RO_$_LLVMIRTest" = private global %struct._class_ro_t { i32 0, i32 8, i32 16, i8* null, i8* getelementptr inbounds ([11 x i8], [11 x i8]* @OBJC_CLASS_NAME_, i32 0, i32 0), %struct.__method_list_t* null, %struct._objc_protocol_list* null, %struct._ivar_list_t* bitcast ({ i32, i32, [1 x %struct._ivar_t] }* @"\01l_OBJC_$_INSTANCE_VARIABLES_LLVMIRTest" to %struct._ivar_list_t*), i8* null, %struct._prop_list_t* null }, section "__DATA, __objc_const", align 8
@"OBJC_CLASS_$_LLVMIRTest" = global %struct._class_t { %struct._class_t* @"OBJC_METACLASS_$_LLVMIRTest", %struct._class_t* @"OBJC_CLASS_$_NSObject", %struct._objc_cache* @_objc_empty_cache, i8* (i8*, i8*)** null, %struct._class_ro_t* @"\01l_OBJC_CLASS_RO_$_LLVMIRTest" }, section "__DATA, __objc_data", align 8
@"OBJC_LABEL_CLASS_$" = private global [1 x i8*] [i8* bitcast (%struct._class_t* @"OBJC_CLASS_$_LLVMIRTest" to i8*)], section "__DATA, __objc_classlist, regular, no_dead_strip", align 8
@llvm.compiler.used = appending global [5 x i8*] [i8* getelementptr inbounds ([11 x i8], [11 x i8]* @OBJC_CLASS_NAME_, i32 0, i32 0), i8* getelementptr inbounds ([9 x i8], [9 x i8]* @OBJC_METH_VAR_NAME_, i32 0, i32 0), i8* getelementptr inbounds ([12 x i8], [12 x i8]* @OBJC_METH_VAR_TYPE_, i32 0, i32 0), i8* bitcast ({ i32, i32, [1 x %struct._ivar_t] }* @"\01l_OBJC_$_INSTANCE_VARIABLES_LLVMIRTest" to i8*), i8* bitcast ([1 x i8*]* @"OBJC_LABEL_CLASS_$" to i8*)], section "llvm.metadata"

!llvm.module.flags = !{!0, !1, !2, !3, !4, !5}
!llvm.ident = !{!6}

!0 = !{i32 1, !"Objective-C Version", i32 2}
!1 = !{i32 1, !"Objective-C Image Info Version", i32 0}
!2 = !{i32 1, !"Objective-C Image Info Section", !"__DATA, __objc_imageinfo, regular, no_dead_strip"}
!3 = !{i32 4, !"Objective-C Garbage Collection", i32 0}
!4 = !{i32 1, !"Objective-C Class Properties", i32 64}
!5 = !{i32 1, !"PIC Level", i32 2}
!6 = !{!"Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are considered module scoped that are initialized at compile time versus runtime.

Most front-ends to LLVM put strings at the module scope and those require a `global` or a `constant` tag. There is a way to store strings on the stack instead but that is a rare occurrence in my experience. I typically create strings as

`@somename = internal constant...`.

The `private` is instructing not to expose the symbols outside of the module.

I assume this is how Objective-C adds type and instrumentation support for classes. If you look at the rest of the output it is likely that the pointers to those strings are getting passed into the RT library (e.g. `%x = load ...`) prior to some call.

**Update after OP added listing**

What you've listed is the 'static' module level constructs representing your class. If you look closely, the class declaration consists of a number of embedded structures and strings. Because these declarations are at the module level they are declared `global` which puts them, as you would expect, in the data segment as it is data after-all and not method implementation. Think of your class as a `structure` containing not only space for your variable 'iVar` but additional information necessary for the Objective-C RT.

So, classes and their variables are considered module level declarations which are represented as data structures at the module level which is marked `global` by LLVM standards. See [LLVM Global Variable](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#global-variables) documentation.

Comment: Hi @frank My only concern is if I declare any iVar then why it is declaring it as global? It is not related to String.

Comment: @SauravNagpal as mentioned the strings are being produced by the compiler for Objective-C support. If you extend your question with the output of the actual Class and iVar it may be easier to understand the difference. It does not imply that the iVar is global, just the strings describing it for what I submit would be fore Run Time Type Information (RTTI) typically to support introspection.

Comment: Hi @frank, Thanks for the reply. But still I am confused and I have added the question with whole class. My only question is why global mention for iVar?